# Proper return type in MVC WEB API after join table result set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This works in my web api:

```
    public IEnumerable<Object> Get()
    {
        var passengerVehicle =
            from vehMake in _Uow.GetRepository<VehicleMake>().Include<VehicleModel>()
            join passVeh in _Uow.GetRepository<PassengerVehicle>().Include<Vehicle>()
                .Include(y => y.Vehicle.VehicleModel)
                .Include(y => y.Vehicle.VehicleSubModel)
                .Include(y => y.Vehicle.VehicleImages)
                .Include(y => y.Vehicle.VehicleLocation)
                .Include(y => y.Vehicle.VehiclePrices)
                on vehMake.Id equals passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleModel.FK_VehicleMakeId
            select new
            {
                vehMake = vehMake.Name,
                vehMod = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleModel.Name,
                vehSubModel = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleSubModel.Name,
                vehLocation = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleLocation,
                vehImages = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleImages.ToList(),
                vehOptions = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleOptions.ToList(),
                vehPostHistories = passVeh.Vehicle.VehiclePostHistories.ToList(),
                vehStats = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleStatistics.ToList(),
                vehStatus = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleStatus,
                vehPrices = passVeh.Vehicle.VehiclePrices.ToList(),
            };

        return passengerVehicle;
    }
```

**I am not delighted that the return type is "object"**

I thought perhaps a HttpResponse but apparently that is not correct either.

PassengerVehicle has an association with Vehicle.

Vehicle has an association with VehicleModel & VehicleSubModel.

VehicleModel has an association with VehicleMake.

Pretty much everything else are primitives or straight up collections.

Suggestions?

Comment: Make a class with just the fields you need to return?

Comment: What about making a concrete type with all those properties instead of an anonymous type ? Like a `VehicleResponseModel` object

Comment: I want to avoid concrete types. I hate concrete types. I want to abstract EVERYTHING! Perhaps, in the end, you may be right and I may be forced to create a PassengerVehicle view model, but I really do not want to.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use ViewModel, like:

```
select new VehicleSpecialViewModel
        {
            vehMake = vehMake.Name,
            vehMod = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleModel.Name,
            vehSubModel = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleSubModel.Name,
            vehLocation = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleLocation,
            vehImages = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleImages.ToList(),
            vehOptions = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleOptions.ToList(),
            vehPostHistories = passVeh.Vehicle.VehiclePostHistories.ToList(),
            vehStats = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleStatistics.ToList(),
            vehStatus = passVeh.Vehicle.VehicleStatus,
            vehPrices = passVeh.Vehicle.VehiclePrices.ToList(),
        };
```

and then your return type would be

```
IEnumerable<VehicleSpecialViewModel>
```

Comment: Yea, I know,. ViewModel, ehh ... [To me, it violates DRY]

Comment: I played once with those stuff like anonymous types, IEnumerable<dynamic> and so on, but in the end I had to gave up. There were few reasons, but main was that after obfuscating, project stopped to run. ViewModel was thought, for stuff you want, and this is strict, clear, and right way to go.